# Printing template parameters in azure devops template

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a task or command that I can use to output all the parameters variable in a Azure DevOps template when the pipeline is run?

I would like the first task in the pipeline to print all parameters, that would help to spot mistakes.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to display template parameters using single command, so your only option is printing them one be one like this:

```yaml
- script: |
    echo 'vmImage - ${{ parameters.vmImage }}'
    echo 'anotherRuntimeParameter - ${{ parameters.anotherRuntimeParameter }}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. tried  
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: 'bash: env | sort'
    
but did not print any of the parameters variables  e.g ${{ parameters.vmImage }} Am I missing something

Comment: @developer9969 Do you insert `- template: parameterTemplate.yml` in azure-pipelines.yml? Here is a reference [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops).

Comment: @Krzysztof hi thank your for your answer . that worked I thought there was something inbuilt but there isnt.

Answer (score 9):

I was also faced with this requirement and found the following solution:

```yaml
    - script: |    
       echo "${{ convertToJson(parameters) }}"
```

Documentation for [convertToJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#converttojson)

Comment: When I tried this, I get output like this '"buildConfig":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,... How do you run this so the terminal does not interpret the output as a command? Thanks

Comment: @ScottHutchinson make sure you have "" around the output (like in the example).

Comment: Answer from @Eyal below seems to work better for me.

Answer (score 4):

I've found this to work for me:
(as just using the respond above gave an error)

```
- powershell: |    
    $jsonParams = '${{ convertToJson(parameters) }}'
    Write-Host $jsonParams
  displayName: 'Print parameters in JSON format'
```

Comment: I had the same issue, and your version worked!